# Modified kernel module doesn't load on boot- is the old one being cached somewhere

Tags: boot, kernel-modules, debugging, dmesg, device-tree

I'm modifying the qca7000 kernel module slightly by adding some debug messages (qcaspi.ko).

I compile, run `depmod` then reboot. However my debug messages do not show up on dmesg.

If I `rmmod qcaspi` then `modprobe qcaspi`, only then do my debug messages show.

Which module is being loaded at boot? And how can this be possible if I'm modifying its .ko file?